# fatal error Varien_Autoload not found

Tags: magento

Goodday everyone,

I installed magento with the sample data I refreshed the page and everything seemed to work. My complete shop was filled with sample data. A couple of minutes after I refreshed again and since then I keep getting this error:

PHP Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /var/www/vhosts/shop.cyberned.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 53

I double checked if Varien_Autoload exists and it is there in lib/Varien/Autoload.php

It looks like that file is not included for some reason but I would have no idea how to get that fixed. So my question is: how do I get this fixed?

Comment: sounds like your `include_path` isn't set up correctly.

Comment: include_path .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php

so I guess that's ok?

Comment: echo $PATH in console to find out what's in your path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error occurs  because of the `lib` folder is not in the `include_path`. This may happen only if the `COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH` constant is defined. Most likely this constant is defined in the `includes/config.php` file.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem, I did following steps and now it is working :)

1. Check Compilation mode is disabled or not in `include/config.php` file. if not then edit and make sure these two lines should be same as written below :-

   ```
   #define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH',dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
   #define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH',dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
   ```
2. Flush magento cache Storage
   `sudo rm -rf var/cache/*`
3. Set Correct Permission
   `sudo chmod -R 755 *`
4. Restart the Webserver (apache/nginx)
5. Now Verify.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the permission problem, Mage.php may not have the right to load the class 'Varien_Autoload'.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions