# Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found

Tags: magento

During deployment of a Magento site I got the following warning and error:-

```
Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxx/subdomain/stage/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxx/subdomain/stage/app/code/local:/home/xxx/subdomain/stage/app/code/community:/home/xxx/subdomain/stage/app/code/core:/home/xxx/subdomain/stage/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/xxx/subdomain/stage/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxx/subdomain/stage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxx/subdomain/stage/app/code/local:/home/xxx/subdomain/stage/app/code/community:/home/xxx/subdomain/stage/app/code/core:/home/xxx/subdomain/stage/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/xxx/subdomain/stage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68

Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home/xxx/subdomain/stage/app/Mage.php on line 53
```

I have already set permission to 777 and set the `include_path` correctly and there is `lib` folder inside includes too but its not working.

Please suggest how to solve this error. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8624719/1749007

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error Varien\_Autoload not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245874/fatal-error-varien-autoload-not-found)