# Error while loading Magento1.7 Varien/Autoload.php

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have installed **Magento** and merged the live server directory to the already installed magento directory, but found error :

> **Fatal error: Class 'Extendware_EWCore_Model_Autoload' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/magento/app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php on line 14**

I have a problem with the `Varien/Autoload.php` file. Can anyone please help me through this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error Varien\_Autoload not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245874/fatal-error-varien-autoload-not-found)

Comment: can you describe about Extendware extension?

Comment: @Jinesh There are around 66 System extensions that are active and 122 3rd party extensions.

Comment: but all are not this firm Extendware. Check in your folder

Comment: @Jinesh Hey, I did not exactly understand where to look at, can you please help me with this

Comment: @Jinesh, Sorry, I am really new to this Magento.

Comment: is it possible to share all files and folder so I can look it you more

Comment: @Jinesh The folders and content of folders are very huge, I have tried solutions like flushing cache and other methods.

I am left with "This error occurs because of the lib folder is not in the include_path. This may happen only if the COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH constant is defined. Most likely this constant is defined in the includes/config.php file."

I have to try this, but I wonder, where we need to include the path. I hope this would answer my question. If not need to find other solutions. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: send me zip of share all files in google drive